# How to change style of active toggled anchor when using jquery toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following to toggle several links on a page with relevant data

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a  class="show" target="1">Option 1</a>
    <a  class="show" target="2">Option 2</a>
    <a  class="show" target="3">Option 3</a>
    <a  class="show" target="4">Option 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 4</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.targetDiv').hide();
$('.show').click(function () {
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle('').siblings('.targetDiv').hide('');
});
```

Which works for what I want just fine but what I would like to know is if it's possible to have the style of the link change when each one is active. So the user knows they're viewing the contents of that link. So if the current show class is background: #000; for example, can I change it to background: #fff; somehow when that option DIV is being displayed? Then back to normal when it's not?

JSfiddle of current setup http://jsfiddle.net/W3HtS/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way :  [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankittyagi/5H4X6/1/)

```
 $('.show').not(this).removeClass('active');
      if($(this).hasClass('active')){
         $(this).removeClass('active');
      }else{
         $(this).addClass('active');
      }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution but please see the responses to the other solution, this one has the same small issue. :)

Comment: Thanks, can't seem to get that new code working at all though? Can you post an updated jsfiddle to see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See the fiddle i have provided.

Answer (score 3):

Add active class name on click function

```
$('.show').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aBoFikAB/3/)**

Comment: Thanks, this works with one small issue. If you close the active button with the same button again the active class remains. It's only if you open one of the others it is gone. Is there any way to fix that, so it returns to normal if you open/close the same div?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('.targetDiv').hide();

   $('.show').click(function () {
            $(".show").removeClass("highlight");
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
        $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle('').siblings('.targetDiv').hide('');
        });
```

define the style that you want to apply in **highlight** class

Comment: Thanks, this also works but again has the same issue as the other solutions.  If you close the active button with the same button again the highlight class remains. It's only if you open one of the others it is gone. I'd prefer it if the style could go back to default when it's closed via the same button.