# Change css 'active' link when using toggle and isotope

Tags: html, css, toggle, jquery-isotope

I have a question regarding [this page](http://spoilers.tumblr.com/2014/) of mine. The menus and submenus are toggled, and I'm using Isotope. I'd like to know if it's possisble to change the style of the link which just got clicked. Since this is all happening in one page, other solutions for this problem don't work.

I can't get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675030/how-to-change-style-of-active-toggled-anchor-when-using-jquery-toggle) to work either, probably because I have to use multiple toggles. (+ There is the added complexity of my tv schedule page, since it's basicly an entire page inside  a toggle.)

I hope someone can help me by taking a look at my source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a css class for your active style instead of the inline style you have currently on "TV Schedule" (background: teal; color: white). Call the class "active" for example.

Simply add and remove this class within your click handler you already have setup with jquery. So at 134 in your source:

```
$('.sort a').click(function(){

  //add these 2 lines
  $('.sort a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  //the rest of your handler
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $container.isotope({
    filter: selector,
    animationOptions: {
      duration: 750,
      easing: 'linear',
      queue: false,
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

The first line goes through and removes it from all the a tags in that block if it exists. The next one adds it to the one that was clicked.

That's usually the way I do this sort of thing. It's independent of isotope - just using the jquery you already have in there.

Comment: It seems to be adding the class. Did you add the active class to your css and style it?

Comment: .sort a.active - it needs to be as specific as the other css applied to that element to override it.

Comment: Hmm, when I do that, the links stop working.. (I'm sorry to bother you with all of this, and thanks for all the help so far!)

Comment: The links still work (the toggle does, the isotope not) if I change "$('.sort a').click(function(){"
 to "$('.sort a.active').click(function(){" but the background doesn't change either.

Comment: Well, hopefully you understand the concept. It's not a complete solution because your submenus are in the same container, so clicking them will remove the class from the parent link as well. You'd need to use the basic concept in a way that works for your site. Adding/removing classes via jquery addClass()/removeClass() is the basic idea.

Comment: Made it work for one of the submenus! (.daynav) Thanks!